# Induction on logic formula

Tags: logic, induction

The term $((\bigvee_{i=1}^{n} p_i) \wedge (\bigwedge_{i=1}^{n} (p_i \to p)) \to p$ should be proven through induction. I'm relatively new to it, but I started with:

**basis**: $p(1): (p_1 \wedge (p_1 \to p)) \to p$ is true (modus ponens)

**induction step**: $((p_1 \vee p_2 \vee ... p_n) \wedge (p_1 \wedge p_2 \wedge ... p_{n-1} (p_n \to p)) \to p$

But I don't know how to go further from this or how to solve it, it would be nice if I could get a clue how to compute it to the end.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your "induction step" is not stated correctly. The correct assumption on the induction step is
$$\Bigl( \bigl(p_1\lor\cdots\lor p_n\bigr) \land \bigl( (p_1\to p)\land (p_2\to p)\land\cdots\land (p_n\to p)\bigr)\Bigr) \to p.$$

From this, you want to show that 
$$\Bigl( \bigl(p_1\lor\cdots\lor p_n\lor p_{n+1}\bigr) \land \bigl( (p_1\to p)\land (p_2\to p)\land\cdots\land (p_n\to p)\land (p_{n+1}\to p)\bigr)\Bigr) \to p$$
also holds.

One possibility is to distribute the $\land$: you have
$$\begin{align*}
&\Bigl( \bigl(p_1\lor\cdots\lor p_n\lor p_{n+1}\bigr) \land \bigl( (p_1\to p)\land (p_2\to p)\land\cdots\land (p_n\to p)\land (p_{n+1}\to p)\bigr)\Bigr) \to p\\
&\equiv \Bigl(\bigl(p_1\lor\cdots \lor p_n\bigr)\land\bigl( \bigwedge_{i=1}^{n+1}(p_i\to p)\bigr) \lor \bigl( p_{n+1}\land\bigl(\bigwedge_{i=1}^{n+1}p_i\to p)\bigr)\Bigr) \to p\\
&\equiv \Biggl(\Bigl(\bigl( p_1\lor\cdots \lor p_n\bigr)\land \bigwedge_{i=1}^{n+1}(p_i\to p)\land (p_{n+1}\to p)\Bigr)\\
&\qquad\lor\Bigl(\bigl(p_{n+1}\land (p_{n+1}\to p)\bigr)\land \bigwedge_{i=1}^{n}(p_i\to p)\bigr)\Bigr)\Biggr)\to p
\end{align*}$$

Now, this expression has the form 
$$\Bigl( \bigl((A\land B)\land C\bigr) \lor \bigl(D\land C)\Bigr)\to p.$$
From the induction hypothesis, you know that $(A\land B)\to p$ and from the $n=1$ case you know that $D\land C\to p$. Hence $(A\land B\land C)\to p$ and $D\land C\to p$.

Answer (score 2):

First understand why the statement holds:

$$((\bigvee_{i=1}^{n} p_i) \wedge (\bigwedge_{i=1}^{n} (p_i \to p)) \to p$$

A concrete example,

$$((A \lor B \lor C) \land ((A \to p) \land (B \to p) \land (C \to p)))\to p$$

In the hypothesis at least one of $A,B,C$ is true, suppose that $B$ is true.. then we could simplify down to

$$(B \land ((A \to p) \land (B \to p) \land (C \to p)))\to p$$

and proving can be done by proving the stronger statement

$$(B \land (B \to p)) \to p$$

and this is modus ponens.

---

One wishes to use "induction" to make this type of reasoning "rigorous". In that case we must understand our assumptions and prove they hold in all cases.

1. In a disjunction $\bigvee_{i=1}^{n} p_i$ "at least one" $p_i$ holds. Formally, you may state this as $\bigvee_{i=1}^{n} p_i \to \exists j, p_j$.
2. Removing a conjunction from a hypothesis is strengthening. Informally we are saying proving $(X_i \land X_j \land \cdots) \to B$ also proves $(Y \land (X_i \land X_j \land \cdots)) \to B$, and this is a theorem you can prove without induction. The only difference was that our $Y$ was in a different location (between $X_i$ and $X_{i+1}$), if you have not shown that logical statements may be viewed equal (iff is an equivalence relation) up to permutation then that can also be proved by a simple induction argument.

Those two steps are essentially all of the argument (that applying these two steps always produces a "modus ponens" situation is evident) I will show how to prove (1) by induction:

- The base case ($n=0$): An empty disjunction is "False" (that is the identity of the $\lor$ moniod) so $\text{False} \to \exists j, p_j$ is trivial by ex falso quodlibet.
- The recursive step ($n \to n+1$): We are given the hypothesis $(\bigvee_{i=1}^{n} p_i) \to \exists j, p_j$ and wish to prove $((\bigvee_{i=1}^{n} p_i) \lor p_{n+1}) \to \exists j, p_j$. This is a simple proof by cases, if $p_{n+1}$ holds then put $j=n+1$ as our witness, if not then $\bigvee_{i=1}^{n} p_i$ holds so we may use our hypothesis to get a proof of $\exists j, p_j$.

Answer (score 2):

Try to understand what this formula says. It says that if (i) one of the $p_i$ is true, (ii) each of the $p_i$ implies $p$, *then* (iii) $p$ must be true.

Here's how your induction proof goes. For $n=1$ it's easy, as you said. Now let's show that the statement for $n$ implies the statement for $n+1$. We are given that (i) one of $p_1,\ldots,p_{n+1}$ is true, (ii) each of the $p_i$ implies $p$. There are two cases. Case A: one of $p_1,\ldots,p_n$ is true. The induction hypothesis implies that $p$ is true. Case B: $p_{n+1}$ is true. Now it's like the base case.

You can formulate exactly this argument in formal logic. It's, as they say, "just a formality". I'll leave that to you.